# Windows 10 does a temporary fast scroll option exist?

Tags: windows-10, mouse, scrolling, default-settings

Is there possibly a way/software(built in is preffered) in windows 10 without "permanently" adjust the default scroll settings but temporary increase scrolling to double the speed by for example holding in an button.

I love my default settings on scroll, but sometimes i really wish i maybe could hold in a button to get super speed temporary to scroll through a big list.

Very few programs such as vscode has this built in, i think by holding "alt" key you get fast scrolling there but i would appreciate a more universal working method for whole windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script will accelerate
wheel scroll by a factor of three when <kbd>Shift</kbd> is pressed
while scrolling:

```
$+WheelUp::          ; "$" for physical wheel event, not when sent as below
    Send {WheelUp 3} ; The 3 means "Send 3 times" and can be altered
    return

$+WheelDown::
    Send {WheelDown 3}
    return
```

Place the script in an `.ahk` file. Test by double-click to launch.
It will have a green "H" icon in the traybar, which you may right-click to Exit.
Once proven as working correctly, you may place it in your Startup folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version of @harrymc's answer which works with AutoHotkey v2. I also added the ability to ignore certain applications:

```php
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
#SingleInstance Force

; Array of windows to ignore
ignoredWindows := ["ahk_exe code.exe", "ahk_exe code_ignore.exe", "ahk_exe minecraftlauncher.exe", "ahk_exe minecraft.exe"]

; Function to check if any of the specified windows is active
IsIgnoredWindowActive() {
    for window in ignoredWindows {
        if (WinActive(window))
            return true
    }
    return false
}

; Special Keys: https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm
; ! = alt
; + = shift
; ^ = ctrl
; # = win
$!WheelUp::
{
    if (!IsIgnoredWindowActive()) {
        Send("{WheelUp 5}")
    }
    return
}

$!WheelDown::
{
    if (!IsIgnoredWindowActive()) {
        Send("{WheelDown 5}")
    }
    return
}
```